# 'Transform.Rotate(Vector3, Space)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I wanted my gameObject to rotate around the y axis until it reached a certain number, but I'm unsure how to procceed.

```
void Update()
{   
    if (target == 1) {
        this.transform.position += new Vector3(1,0,1) * Time.deltaTime * speed;

        // this next part is where I'm lost:

        if (this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y < 30f) {
            this.transform.Rotate.eulerAngles += (0,1,0, Space.Self);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe you just use `transform.Rotate(0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, Space.Self);` If you want it to rotate over a given time, you would need to Lerp. You are using `Rotate`, which is a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) is a **method** and you **would** use it like

```
void Update()
{   
    if (target == 1) 
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(1,0,1) * Time.deltaTime * speed;

        if (this.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y < 30f) 
        {
            this.transform.Rotate(0, 1 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
```

Note that I changed two things:

- your code is frame-rate dependent! Rather multiply the amount of rotation (just as you did with the position) by `Time.deltaTime` in order to convert it from value/frame into value/second. Of course this currently would rotate with only 1°/second .. you probably want something faster
- `Space.Self` is the default value for the optional parameter `space` so you only have to pass it in if you want to use `Space.World`

**However**, there is another flaw

[`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html) shouldn't be used at all for assigning or checking continously updated values!

> When using the .eulerAngles property to set a rotation, it is important to understand that although you are providing X, Y, and Z rotation values to describe your rotation, those values are not stored in the rotation. Instead, the X, Y & Z values are converted to the Quaternion's internal format.
>
> When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation. See bottom scripting example for more information.

You might want to consider to rather pre-calculate the target rotation as a `Quaternion` e.g. like

```
Quaternion targetRotation;

private void Start ()
{
    targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 30, 0);
}
```

and then later rather use e.g. [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html)

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationAbglesPerSecond);
```